# Power Apps: Submitting a form to a SharePoint List does not record the values for all columns

Tags: powerapps, sharepoint-list

I have a Power app connected to a SharePoint List. The app's purpose is to act as a data entry form for the List. There are 5 dropdowns in the form and the available selections for each depend on the selection of the previous dropdown. When a user fills out the form and submits it, the new record shows up in the SharePoint list. However, not all values are accounted for in the List that were filled out in the app. In fact, 3 of the 5 values push through but 2 remain blank. Here's what I've checked:

-Data source is connected to the form and is refreshed.

-Field names in the app match the original field names in the SharePoint list.

Is there a setting I'm missing?

Comment: Since you established a relationship between the dropdowns, maybe you could check the  Update property of the form cards. Additionally, you could use the Monitor functionality in Power Apps Studio to record a form submission and analyze what exactly is sent from your app to SP.

Comment: If you are using choice columns in SharePoint, you have to patch those using proper value/syntax, check this: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/How-to-Save-Choice-field-value-using-UpdateIf-Patch-functions/td-p/28338. Let me know if this works for you.